# bash: how to copy multiple copies of one file into another fast?

Tags: bash, cat, replicate

I need to stress-test a program by feeding it input files of progressively larger sizes. I have an input file `inputSmall.txt` which I want to replicate `N` times and `cat` those copies into the same file. `N` is large file. If there anything that would work faster than the following simple loop (e.g. `N=1000`):

```
for i in {1..1000}
do 
    cat inputSmall.txt >> input1000.txt
done
```

My machine has enough disk space to store `inputN.txt` for very large `N`s and has a lot of RAM, in case it's relevant.

Thx

Comment: `for i in {1..1000}; do cat inputSmall.txt; done >> input1000.txt` might be theoretically faster, but I don't know if it makes a difference in practice.

Comment: `cat inputSmall.txt{,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,} >> inputNN.txt` works but requires the right number of commas. You could generate the brace string but then you would need to use `eval cat inputSmall.txt{$commavar}` to execute it which isn't pleasant.

Comment: `for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do printf '%s\0' inputSmall.txt; done | xargs -0 cat >input1000.txt` is another small/minimal approach, at least minimizing the number of `cat` invocations and the number of times the output file is opened (but not minimizing the number of times the input file is reread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat` is an external command, rather than being part of the shell; like all external commands, starting it up has a significant overhead. Similarly, running `>>input1000.txt` is a fairly expensive filesystem operation -- looking up the inode associated with a directory, opening it, and then (on leaving scope) flushing contents and closing the file.

It's much more efficient to do these things only once.

---

Assuming that the final line of `inputSmall.txt` ends in a newline, the following will work correctly, and with far less overhead:

```
in=$(<inputSmall.txt)        # read the input file only once
exec 3>>input1000.txt        # open the output file only once

for ((i=0; i<1000; i++)); do
  printf '%s\n' "$in" >&3    # write the input from memory to the output fd
done
exec 3>&-                    # close the output fd
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
for i in {1..1000}
```

You are telling the shell to first write all numbers from 1 to 1000 to the command buffer, and then iterate over each one. For large numbers this is not only slow, bur also adds significant memory requirements (See for example [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153928/bash-crashed-with-for-loop/153937#153937) at unix.se).

In bash you can avoid all this by using the following syntax:

```
for ((i=1; i<=1000;i++))
```

As a bonus, this allows for the bounds to be variables.

Comment: This is true, but it's a much smaller expense than re-opening the output file once per loop iteration is.

Answer (score 0):

this way you can do it faster and "exponential", but you will need to have some extra disk space for the tmp file.

```
input=$1

new=${input}.new.txt
tmp=${input}.tmp.txt

cat ${input} > ${new}
cat "" > ${tmp}

# 2^10=1024
for ((i=0; i<10 ; i++))
do
        cat ${new} >> ${tmp}
        cat ${tmp} >> ${new}
done

rm ${tmp}
```

Comment: Each of these truncates, meaning you get a very different result from the original code.

Comment: This is still a very different result if the file requires more than one write call: You can have contents interleaved. It's also leaving lots of potential performance enhancements on the floor: You're starting `cat` 1000 times, reading the input file 1000 times, opening the output file 1000 times, etc.

Comment: update again, but didn't test it for large files 100MB+
 ,you didn't define what "large" means :)

Comment: In this case, "large" means more than one write block. That's typically never more than 8kb, might be as small as 512 bytes depending on details of the runtime platform.

Comment: BTW, every time you run `>> ${new}`, that's re-opening the output file -- thus, paying a performance expense.

Comment: BTW, the curly braces in `${new}` and `${tmp}` have no effect here -- you'd have the exact same behavior with `$new` or `$tmp` -- but the lack of quoting is a bug: If called with a space in the filename, this code would break. To avoid that, quotes need to be used: `"$new"`, `"$tmp"`, etc.

Comment: (You don't even need the curly braces in `${input}.new.txt`, since `.` isn't valid in shell variable names, though having it is much more defensible as a good practice in that case).

Comment: i prefer using the curly braces everywhere, in many case when mixing variables and strings it is a must to have, you are right that in a lot of times its not required.

Comment: not sure how much difference does it take when talking about 8KB files, you will need someone else help and might be better to add these details to the main question.

Comment: Your new version doesn't have the bug on large files anyhow since you're no longer using `&`.